# How to move a file in sftp using renci library?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017, sftp, ssh.net

I am attempting to move file, yet nothing happens and no exceptions are reported.

```
    public static void MoveFiles(string source, string destination, LoginInfo loginInfo)
    {
        using (SftpClient sftp = new SftpClient(loginInfo.Uri, loginInfo.Port, loginInfo.User, loginInfo.Password))
        {
            foreach (SftpFile file in sftp.ListDirectory(source))
            {
                file.MoveTo(destination + file.Name);
            }
        }
    }
```

The debugger simply steps out of the `foreach`:

[image]

**What am I doing wrong?**

I am using the following dependencies:

```
using Renci.SshNet;
using Renci.SshNet.Sftp;
```

Comment: You forgot to ‘Connect‘ first

Comment: You need to connect the client to the server first https://github.com/zeevl/Renci.SshNet/blob/master/Renci.SshNet/BaseClient.cs#L186

Comment: you guys are both right, but why isnt there any kind of exception thrown?

Comment: wrap it in a try-catch and see if one is caught

Comment: @Nkosi i dont know what i would do without you man.  you've been so helpful to me over these past few years. thank you for everything that you do.

Comment: My suspicion is that the error is happening on another thread so it is not bubbling up from the invoked method. Having the catch in the method allow you to catch it locally and handle it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to connect the client to the server first using

```
sftp.Connect();
```

[Source](https://github.com/zeevl/Renci.SshNet/blob/master/Renci.SshNet/BaseClient.cs#L186)

And you should also wrap it in a try-catch in case of any errors.

```
public static void MoveFiles(string source, string destination, LoginInfo loginInfo) {
    try {
        using (SftpClient sftp = new SftpClient(loginInfo.Uri, loginInfo.Port, loginInfo.User, loginInfo.Password)) {
            sftp.Connect();
            var files = sftp.ListDirectory(source)
            foreach (SftpFile file in files) {
                file.MoveTo(destination + file.Name);
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        //...handle
    }
}
```